# Data processing agreement with license seller or Saas host

Tags: gdpr

If we (company) are buying a Saas licenses via a reseller, do we need a data processing agreement with the reseller or with the origial Saas provider.

Example:
We buy a hosted email services. Company Z is the original provider of this email service, but we do not buy the licenses from company Z, but instead we buy from a local IT shop, company A.
Do we need to have a data processing agreement with Company Z or Company A?
Company A is in this example just a reseller of the license.

Answer (score 0):

A DPA is typically between the software company and a third party.  Company Z would need a DPA with Company A if they use Company A to process your data.  Your Software License Agreement or Master Services Agreement with the software provider protects you.  Company A uses a DPA to protect your data for you if hey contract out services for your data.